# Getting ReferenceError: err is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocha.js, supertest

I am new to js trying to learn `supertest` and stuck in this error.

```
import { describe } from "mocha";
import supertest from "supertest";
import { expect } from "chai";

const request = supertest('https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/');

const api_token = '45faa1e4b06b3cc1d5ecfbe639235376838cf638c85f88cb9bcc04e954bbf77f';

describe('GET /user' , () =>{
  it('fetching user details', (done) =>{
    request.get(`users?access-token=${api_token}`).end((err,res), () =>{
       console.log(err);
        console.log(res.body);  
       // expect(res.body).to.not.be.empty;
       done();

    })
  })
})
```

Getting an error with message `err is not defined`.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are not declaring the callback correctly.

Change this:

```
request.get(`users?access-token=${api_token}`).end((err,res), () =>{
```

to this:

```
request.get(`users?access-token=${api_token}`).end((err,res) =>{
```

The error occurs because you try to pass `(err, res)` all by itself as an argument to `.end()`, but neither of those variables exist in the current scope so you get a ReferenceError on the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for passing callback function is incorrect. end() takes one callback function so you need to change `.end((err,res), () =>{` to `.end((err,res) =>{`